# Использование результата ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Не получается использовать результат выполнения ajax-запроса.

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax_que.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data_db) {
        var answer = data_db;
        console.log(data_db);
        for(var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
            console.log(answer[i]);
        }
    },
    complete: function draw(){}
});
```

Собственно, если я использую цикл внутри ajax

```
for(var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
            console.log(answer[i]);
        }
```

То все ок.

Но мне же нужно работать с answer (это ассоциативный массив) внутри функции draw.

Answer (score 0):

1. А вам он реально нужен?  У вас же `success` отработал и данные уже есть.
2. В `complete` же можно тоже вытащить данные.

Как-то так:

```
 complete: function draw(res){
     var answer = res;
 }
```

Comment: да, реально. В draw этот ассоциативный массив должен использоваться)